# Online/Offline events not firing in Cordova?

Tags: events, cordova

My Resume, Ready and Paused events work just fine. I have problem with online/offline events. When I put my device in Airplane mode and vice verse nothing happens. When I disconnect from Internet I don't get any result. This is My code:

```
var app ={

initialize:function() {
    this.bindEvents();
    this.testzone = {};
},

bindEvents:function(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady,false);
    document.addEventListener("pause", this.onPause,false);
    document.addEventListener("resume", this.onResume,false);
},

onDeviceReady:function() {
    document.addEventListener("online", this.onOnline,false);
    document.addEventListener("offline", this.onOffline,false);
    console.log("Readyii");
    app.testzone = document.getElementById("test-zone");
    app.testzone.innerHTML = "Readyii";
},

onPause: function() {
    app.testzone.innerHTML += "<br />Paused";
},

onResume: function() {
    app.testzone.innerHTML += "<br />Resumed";
},

onOnline: function() {
    app.testzone.innerHTML += "<br />Online";
},

onOffline: function() {
    app.testzone.innerHTML += "<br />Offline";
}



}
```

The below codes were actually in bindEvents at first, but I moved them inside onDeviceReady:

```
    document.addEventListener("online", this.onOnline,false);
    document.addEventListener("offline", this.onOffline,false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the scope of the method calls in your `online` and `offline` eventlisteners.

So instead of `this.onOnline` use `app.onOnline` (or replace app with the parent).

```
document.addEventListener("online", app.onOnline,false);
document.addEventListener("offline", app.onOffline,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using addEventListener

```
document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
```

use this

```
if(window.navigator.onLine){ alert('online'); }else{ alert('offline'); }
```

after adding the "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information" the
window.navigation.onLine will work on mobile